# Could not find method androidTestcompile() for arguments [com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2

Tags: android

I got this error when cleaning my project in android studio:

> Could not find method androidTestcompile() for arguments [com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2, build_617cugq1kph89i9g65xvxcp1i$_run_closure3$_closure7@c93fd3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Builde.gradle:

```
        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestcompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    } )

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testimplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I think you just need to capitalize the C, making it `androidTestCompile`

Comment: @BenP. oooh thank you! you saved my time!